# Covert date string to datetime

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have my date string as `17-06-2017` and I want to create it in format `2017-06-14 10:49:50` to insert in mysql database, nut I'm not able to do it like :

```
var now = new Date(2017-06-17).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Gives

`"1970-01-01 00:00:01"`

And

```
var now = new Date(17-06-2017).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Gives

`"1969-12-31 23:59:57"`;

Need some accurate calculations here, don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you are doing inside the brackets here is a simple subtraction:
`new Date(17-06-2017)` this will spit out a negative number.
What you want to do is something like that:

```js
var now = new Date(2017,06,17).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
console.log(now)
```

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the date into string like this:

```
new Date("2017-06-17")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using moment.js , it is the best library to work with dates , format , timezones.

```
let now = new Date();
let formattedDate = moment(now).format("YYYYMMDD HHMISS");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment and do

```
var date=moment(yourdate).format(yourformat)
```